# "Open in..."-Link for PDF with Trigger.io

Tags: javascript, trigger.io, forge

I'm still fighting with PDF documents and Trigger.io / Forge.

Is it possible to open a PDF document in an external application out of a Trigger.io app the same way the WebView / Safari does? If yes, how do I manage this?

[image: Example in Safari]

Comment: Hey, are you talking about PDF files that are bundled locally in the app itself?

Comment: Hm, not really bundled. I'm fetching the PDF files with an Ajax request and store/cache them locally within the app. Later I would like to display them and let the user open the file also in external applications (iOS only).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, you can use our modal views to display a PDF - I've put together a little demo app here to show that: https://github.com/goodgravy/forge-spikes/tree/master/pdf-reader

Note that this wouldn't work on Android because the webview doesn't include a PDF reader.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your demo code. Viewing PDF files works perfect, but we need the "Open in..."-functionality of iOS, as seen above in the screenshot, which doesn't work out of the box with modal views. Do you have any ideas how we can implement that? Maybe with a native plugin?

Comment: Ah, got it - yes you might want to look at UIDocumentInteractionController: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/PreviewingandOpeningItems.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010410-SW1